# ActiveRecord, Sinatra and Postgres - cant link to my db

Tags: ruby, postgresql, sinatra, sinatra-activerecord

I cant seem to get my Postgres db to link to my Sinatra app using Active record. I'm getting the following error when I run db:migrate

```
ActiveRecord::NoDatabaseError: FATAL:  database "localhost/till" does not exist
```

I ran dbcreate mydb and that went through without problem, and it definitely exists.

I have a config folder and an environment.rb file with

```
db = URI.parse(ENV['DATABASE_URL'] || 'postgres:///localhost/mydb')

ActiveRecord::Base.establish_connection(
  adapter: db.scheme == 'postgres' ? 'postgresql' : db.scheme,
  host: db.host,
  username: db.user,
  password: db.password,
  database: db.path[1..-1],
  encoding: 'utf8'
)
```

Im referencing the file in my app.rb so thats not the problem. Any help gratefully appreciated.

Comment: Have you run `rake db:create` prior to migrating?

Comment: Yes. I removed one of the three /// and now I'm getting Errno::ENOENT: No such file or directory @ rb_sysopen - db/schema.rb. Do I have to generate a schema somehow?

Answer (score 1):

Do you have a migration file that you are using to create the tables in the database? When you migrate that should generate the schema file. To create a migration file, `cd` to your app folder and enter the terminal command `bundle exec rake db:create_migration NAME=my_migration_name`. That will create a `db` folder in your app folder which will contain a `migrate` folder. In the `migrate` folder there will be a file. That will will look like this:

```
class Migration < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
  end
end
```

In the `change` function is where you can create tables. To create a table add into the `change` function a `create_table` function, as shown below.

```
class MyMigrationFile < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :my_table_name do |i|
      i.string :my_column_name
      # string is the type of variable this column will store, you can change that if you want
    end
  end
end
```

Then to actually create the tables you need to migrate. To migrate, or actually create the tables enter the terminal command `bundle exec rake db:migrate`. That will generate your schema file.